# Constraints in Xcode (Swift 2 iOS App)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, adaptive-layout

I'm making a simple iOS app in xcode using Swift and while I have the entire backend figured out (and it works perfectly), I don't understand constraints AT ALL. I'm trying to make my layout adaptive so it works on all iphone screens but I'm having a really difficult time. Any suggestions on how I can create the perfect layout? Resources would be helpful too. Most resources don't explain the concept or start from scratch.

Another issue I'm having is that every time I click on something, e.g. a table cell, and uncheck "Constrain to margins" and set the constraints, the changes aren't saved and as soon as I hit enter they revert back to the original settings.

REALLY lost on this whole constraints thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So for learning constraints, I would advice you to do this tutorial. It is lengthy but it covers a lot of important concepts.

www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

As for constraint to margins, you need to deselect "constraint to margins" before you edit the values. And once you edit a value, make sure the red lines are activated, and do not click on add constraints until you are sure of all the values. (1)

[(Image 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Upd.png)

You can check and edit the constraint in this window, just select your view and go here (2)

[(image 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7wVc.png)

Comment: Thanks, that helped!